# Как надежно синхронизировать записи между мобильным приложением и базой MySql?

Tags: android, mysql, база-данных, синхронизация

Задача простая, но не могу понять как сделать надёжную синхронизацию.

Есть мобильное приложение на андройд (`SQLite`).
К примеру в нем таблица Table:
`(_id, field, id_base)` где `id_base` - `id` с базы сервера

Есть база (`mysql`).
Таблица Table `(id, field)`.

Алгоритм:

1. В приложении сохраняю запись: `_id=1, field="blabla", id_base=0`.
2. Отправляю в `mysql` (через `php`), там записывается:

   `id (autoinc) (он же id_base в приложении) = 1, field ="blabla"`
3. Возвращаю `id_base` в приложение чтобы там его записать в запись и в дальнейшем понимать что эти записи связаны.

Всё хорошо в принципе работает, но кроме случая если запрос на сохранения отправили на сервер, запись там сохранилась, но по какой-либо причине в приложение не дошёл `id_base`. Поэтому связи между записями не происходит и в следующий раз снова создаётся новая вторая запись в `mysql`.

Как организовать работу синхронизации, чтобы гарантированно понимать, что записи синхронизировались?

Comment: Приложение должно помнить, что оно создало, отправило, но не получило подтверждения. И агрессивно долбиться в MySQL до тех пор, пока подтверждение либо его отсутствие не будет получено (на старте приложения, регулярно при работе...). А также при попытке запроса операции, которая может потенциально привести к задваиванию, оповещать оператора о наличии неподтверждённой транзакции и потенциальном задваивании, с запросом, что делать - слать? ждать? сохранить черновик?

Answer (score 4):

- Для каждой записи создаётся уникальный request_id. Сервер должен различать разные request_id.
- У каждой записи должен быть local_id (тот, что назначен в приложении при создании записи) и remote_id (тот, что получен в ответе сервера, при обновлении).
- Сервер сравнивает айдишники запросов (request_id) и на один и тот же реквест будет отвечать одинаковым id записи (со своей базы). Таким образом хоть сто раз пришли одинаковый реквест, респонс будет один и тот же.

Логика работы:

1. Создаём запись, присваиваем ей свой собственный local_id и генерируем request_id.
2. Идём к серверу. Если запрос прошёл хорошо, в респонсе мы получили remote_id который и записали нашей записи.
3. Если не прошёл или отвалился по таймауту - создаём периодическую задачу, по которой кто то (например, сервис JobScheduler) будет тыкаться на сервер по всем записям, у которых нет remote_id. Как только запрос пройдёт - мы запишем себе remote_id и на этом всё будет хорошо.